# Hadoop: Array of primitives as value in a key value pair

Tags: java, arrays, hadoop, key-value, writable

I have asked a very resemblant question in a previous thread [Hadoop: How can i have an array of doubles as a value in a key-value pair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342243/hadoop-how-can-i-have-an-array-of-doubles-as-a-value-in-a-key-value-pair) .

My problem is that i want to pass a double array as value from map to reduce phase. The answer i got was to serialize, convert to Text, pass it to the reducer and deserialize. This is a fine solution but its like serializing and deserializing it twice.

ArrayWritable only accepts types that implement Writable like FloatWritable for example. So another solution is to convert my array of doubles to an array of DoubleWritables. But this requires some time too and Writables are a very expensive resource. Isn't there a very simple solution like ArrayWritable array=new ArrayWritable(Double.class) ???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just implement your own [Writable](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Writable.html) interface.

For example,

```
public class DoubleArrayWritable implements Writable {
    private double[] data;

    public DoubleArrayWritable() {

    }

    public DoubleArrayWritable(double[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public double[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(double[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
        int length = 0;
        if(data != null) {
            length = data.length;
        }

        out.writeInt(length);

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            out.writeDouble(data[i]);
        }
    }

    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        int length = in.readInt();

        data = new double[length];

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            data[i] = in.readDouble();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah i believe that this will fit my case. I was influenced by the ArrayWritable and never thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `double[]` as the value type for a `Map`:

```
Map<String, double[]> map = new HashMap<String, double[]>(); // compiles
```

Java arrays are automatically `Serializable` if the element type is `Serializable`, and primitives are all `Serializable`.

Comment: This is a hadoop key value pair, not from a map structure. The guy from the previous thread also thought i was referring to a map structure. Cant anyone see the hadoop word?