# issue with Array output value (HADOOP)

Tags: dictionary, hadoop, mapreduce

i have this in my Mapper code,where 'a' is a DoubleWritable array.

```
DoubleArrayWritable ad = new DoubleArrayWritable();
ad.set(a);
int row_id1=(int)row_id;
context.write(new LongWritable(row_id1),new Text(ad.toString()));
```

and i m just printing these inputs to reducer as output of reducer and i m getting this as output from reducer,

```
1   DoubleArrayWritable@e29820
2   DoubleArrayWritable@718242
3   DoubleArrayWritable@1ec58a
4   DoubleArrayWritable@3afb99
```

what am i missing ? i want output as

```
 1  2 3 4 7
 2  4 6 5 9
 3  4 5 7 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `DoubleArrayWritable` class, I'm assuming you're using the code from the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12878375/3009). If that's the case, you'll need to implement `toString` to output in the format you want.  Maybe something like:

```
public String toString() {
    if (data.length == 0) {
      return "";
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (double d : data) {
        sb.append(d).append(" ");
    }

    //trim the trailing space
    sb.setLength(sb.length - 1);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

If you can live with a format like this:

> [1, 2, 3, 4]

you can skip the `toString` method and do this instead:

```
context.write(new LongWritable(row_id1),new Text(Arrays.toString(ad.getData())));
```

Comment: thanks i did like that ... now can u please tell me how to get some prior data from a separate file which i can use to process my input data in reducer.like i have some sum stored in one or more file and now i want to divide every input i m getting from mapper in reducer by that sum. (i m new to HADOOP, please try to answer accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try that:

```
context.write(new LongWritable(row_id1),new Text(String.valueOf(ad)));
```

I'm using that for string to Text conversions.